# child.parentNode.removeChild(child) keeps giving a TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and for an assignment I have to remove a div from a facebook post. I'm using

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
```

to find the div, since FB doesn't use ID tags. I can get a value if i run the var but its not working with removeChild for some reason.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Please show the part that doesn't work. The code you've shown doesn't look for `<div>` elements, it looks for all elements with `class="Div"`, and returns a list of zero or more elements (depending on how many matched). You can't use `.parentNode` on a list.

Comment: The clue is in the function name getElement s ByClassName. IOW you can return zero or more elements therefore you need to test the returned array length and values.

Comment: Div was supposed to represent the div class name, the actual div name is "mtm" that i want to remove

Comment: Please read [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for how to use *getElementsByClassName* correctly. It returns a live NodeList, which doesn't have a *parentNode* property, hence you see an error when trying to access the *removeChild* method of *undefined*.

Comment: @RobG Oh, that makes sense. Is there anyway to do this in JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getElementsByClassName returns list of elements.
```

Let us say you have a class with name "class1" attached to multiple elements inside the document, it will return all the elements with class name "class1".
You can iterate though result of getElementsByClassName like normal array. 
For example:

if you want to remove first element that matches with this class name. then

```
el[0].parentNode.removeChild(el[0]).
```

But i would suggest having better logic to remove this element.

Comment: This works for what I need!

Comment: glad to know that it helped