# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following markup:

```
<div>
  <div class="form-action form-action-primary">
   <button class="button button-chevron-right button-primary" name="next" type="submit" value="Next">
            Next
          <span class="icon icon-icon-cta"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following javascript to remove the button:

```
window.onload = function (){

    var elem = document.getElementsByName('next');
    console.log(elem);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
};
```

but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined
at window.onload
```

console.log returns:

```
NodeList [button.button.button-chevron-right.button-primary]
```

Comment: For starters I think you can't call `removeChild` on a `NodeList`, which is what `getElementsByName` returns. Please add the output of `console.log(elem)` to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [child.parentNode.removeChild(child) keeps giving a TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152377/child-parentnode-removechildchild-keeps-giving-a-typeerror-cannot-read-proper)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) ***returns a NodeList Collection of elements with a given name in the document***, to access any element from it you should use the specific *index*:

You can try with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which ***returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors*** and attribute selector:

```js
window.onload = function (){
    var elem = document.querySelector('[name=next]');
    console.log(elem);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-action form-action-primary">
   <button class="button button-chevron-right button-primary" name="next" type="submit" value="Next">
      Next
      <span class="icon icon-icon-cta"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are querying for elements by class name, you will receive an array.

Just change this line: `var elem = document.getElementsByName('next');`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByName('next')[0]; // Element at index 0
  console.log(elem);
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-action form-action-primary">
    <button class="button button-chevron-right button-primary" name="next" type="submit" value="Next">
            Next
          <span class="icon icon-icon-cta"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
</div>
```